# Alphabetical Sort collection objects by custom model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, methods, collections, models

I have a method in my `User` model called `display_name`. In my controller I want to sort all the `User` objects by their `display_name` in alphabetical order. `display_name` returns a string, how do I do this?

### User

```
  def display_name
      if !addressbook.b_company.nil?
        if addressbook.b_company.downcase[0..3] == "the "
                addressbook.b_company[4..-1]
        else
                addressbook.b_company
        end
      else
          "#{addressbook.b_lastname}, #{addressbook.b_firstname}"
      end
  end
```

Comment: I am already using this gem: https://github.com/versioneye/naturalsorter to sort various things in my application. If theres no other way I wouldn't mind using this gem.

Comment: your code smells a bit: you don't need to use `self` when you are just reading an attribute, moreover, the keyword `return` is optional in ruby and could be removed since all methods will return the last evaluated expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and pass it your method:

```
@users.sort_by(&:display_name).each do |user|
  # your code here
end
```

Comment: this isnt working, `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass` (@users) I have `@users = User.all` then `@users.sort_by(&:display_name)` in my index action

Comment: also, .each iterator is called in the view, all of that syntax is correct

Comment: it complains about `@users` being nil, are you sure it is not?

Comment: looks like my problem is elsewhere